# How do I view the different texture paint of multiple objects simultaneously?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I have uploaded a couple of rigs and they all have their own texture paint but I don't know how to show them at the same time. For example I can show woody and Boba Fett's texture paints at different times but not at the same time.[image]
[image]

Comment: Does going into material preview or render preview mode allow you to see both of them?

Comment: I wasn't able to find render preview mode but click z then material previews and that worked so thanks Christopher Esther!

Comment: Glad that worked. I'll go ahead and add this as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to view multiple textures simultaneously, change the viewport shading mode to either *Material Preview* or *Rendered*. *Material Preview* will allow you to view all of the materials in a scene and *Rendered* will provide a preview of what the rendered scene will look like.

To switch modes, use the four icons located at the top right hand corner of the viewport. The modes (from left to right) are Wireframe, Solid, Material Preview, and Rendered.
[image: Four icons in the top right hand corner of the viewport used for switching view mode.]